# How do I log into a website in an IOS APP through swift/javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to create an application where the user sign's in through my UI. I have textLabel's that I'm pulling data from, I want to taje that data and use it to log into a website online and get data once logged in. What I have right now is a WKWebView that is invisible most of the time that loads the website I want to log into it, then fills out the log in forms and clicks the button - all via evaluateJavaScript. My only problem right now is that I'm trying to come up with something that will be able to check if the user logged in incorrectly. What I am trying to do is wait till the javascript executes, then check the webView and see if the url has changed to the log in page. This works, however only if the user hasn't failed to enter a correct password. If they get an incorrect password once, all the entries after that say the password is incorrect. Im using an observe value to check if the page is done loading but i need help implementing this.

```
@IBAction func loginBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if(!validate(usernameText) || !validate(passwordText))
    {
        self.validationLabel.text = "One or more fields are empty."
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.validationLabel.isHidden = false
        })
        return;
    }
    let oldUrl = webView.url?.absoluteString;
    self.validationLabel.isHidden = true

        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('fieldAccount').value = \(usernameText!.text!)", completionHandler: {(result,err) in print(result ?? "No Result"); print (err ?? "No Error") })
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('fieldPassword').value = '\(passwordText!.text!)'", completionHandler: {(result,err) in print(result ?? "No Result"); print (err ?? "No Error") })
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('btn-enter').click()", completionHandler: {(result,err) in
            print(result ?? "No Result"); print (err ?? "No Error") })


    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(6), execute: {
            // Put your code which should be executed with a delay here


    if(self.webView.url?.absoluteString.contains("termGrades"))!
    {
        print("We're in bois: ")
        self.view = self.webView
    }else
    {


        print("Did not get to grades page..")

        self.validationLabel.text = "Invalid Username/Password"
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            self.validationLabel.isHidden = false
        })
        let portalURL = URL(string: "*website*")
        let request = URLRequest(url: portalURL!)
        self.webView.load(request)

        return;

        }




     }) }
```

I'm a new ios developer but I don't want to give up on this, If you have any help , or suggestions on a better way to wait for the javascript to click the button and the page to fullyload please share

EDIT: 
I think I found a solution but for some reason now the login button has to be clicked twice for it to process anything...

```
@IBAction func loginBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    if(!validate(usernameText) || !validate(passwordText))
    {
        self.validationLabel.text = "One or more fields are empty."
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.validationLabel.isHidden = false
        })
        return;
    }
    self.validationLabel.isHidden = true

        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('fieldAccount').value = \(usernameText!.text!.description)", completionHandler: {(result,err) in print(result ?? "No Result"); print (err ?? "No Error") })
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('fieldPassword').value = '\(passwordText!.text!)'", completionHandler: {(result,err) in print(result ?? "No Result"); print (err ?? "No Error") })
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('btn-enter').click()", completionHandler: {(result,err) in
            print(result ?? "No Result"); print (err ?? "No Error") })
}


override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "loading"
    {
        if(!webView.isLoading) {
            print("Finished navigating to url \(webView.url!)");
            if(webView.url! == URL(string: "**"))
            {
                statusLabel.text = "Done."
            }else if(webView.url! == URL(string: "**"))
            {
                self.validationLabel.text = "Invalid Username/Password"
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                    self.validationLabel.isHidden = false
                })
            }else if(webView.url! == URL(string: "**"))
            {
                self.view = webView
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`func webView(webView: WKWebView!, didFinishNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("Finished navigating to url \(webView.url)");
  }`

Make sure to set the delegate of the WKWebView to your view controller